# Calculation in entities

Tags: spring, design-patterns, model, entity, spring-data

I have an `@Entity`. I want to make calculations on its fields.
The problem is that I need to use extra constant parameters for some calculations that came from a `@Service`.
How should I handle this problem? Probably I shouldn't autowire a service into a model.

Another option is to make a service for the model to handle all the calculations and store results in the model. I don't like it, because recalculations are more problematic and formulas are not stored together with the model.

Any idea?

Comment: What kind of  calculations and will they persist with the DB?

Comment: Calculations won't be persisted in DB. I need calculations like the product of a field and a constant or sum of two fields. I want to get the result of the calculations via getters so they are recalculated every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you need to implement an adapter design pattern.

> The adapter pattern is a structural design pattern. In the adapter
>   pattern, a wrapper class (ie, the adapter) is used translate requests
>   from it to another class (ie, the adaptee). In effect, an adapter
>   provides particular interactions with an adaptee that are not offered
>   directly by the adaptee.

You need to implement a adapter class which holds both your entity and parameters from your `@Service` (Adaptee1 and Adaptee2 in the UML) . Calculations can be done in the adapter methods (lets say methodA in the UML)

[image]

There is no need to set Adapter class to spring context. A dynamic instance can be created in the client code, most possibly in your `@Service` bean.

[image]

I find avajava design patterns tutorial simple and usefull, then i recommend you to have a look.

**See also**

[Adapter Pattern avajava.com](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/adapter-pattern.html?page=2)

[Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

[Examples of GoF Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/892994)